# Using stored procedure to get data from multiple columns and display it in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I want to display data from two tables in a view with the help of a stored procedure. I'm getting stuck in retrieving records, can't write view model class in `DbSet` as its wrong, have posted my code.

And also I want to pass data from the controller to view in strongly typed.

Please refer snap short for further understanding.

[image]

The count of data is correct but there is no data in it.

Model

```
public class tblStudents
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class tblStudentDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

//This class contains columns from both the tables
public class AllDataa
{
    public class Dataa
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
 public class VMStudentDetails
 {
    public List<tblStudents> students { get; set; }

    public tblStudentDetails StudentDetails { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AllDataa> AllData { get; set; }
 }
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_StudentDetail
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        S.Name, SD.Address 
    FROM
        tblStudents S
    INNER JOIN 
        tblStudentDetails SD ON S.Id = Sd.StudentId
END
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var model = new MVCLearning.Models.VMStudentDetails();
        //What to write in Sqlquery? 
       //model.AllData = db.Database.SqlQuery<>("usp_StudentDetail").ToList();
      //This is not working the data is not coming in Alldata
       model.AllData = db.Database.SqlQuery<AllDataa>("usp_StudentDetail").ToList();
          return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Unless there is some other issue due to wrong parameter or name mismatch.  db.Database.SqlQuery should work

Comment: Sir its a normal SQL select call,any parameter is not involved in it.

Comment: I would recommend you checking the underlying SQL generated by entity framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first approach,  then the recommended way would be to join both the tables through code like below

```
from student in tblStudents
Join details in tblStudentDetails
On student.id equals details.studentid 
Select new AllData() {Id =student.id, name = student. Name, Address =details.Address}
```

This is more similar to SP you have written

Comment: Yes its similar to it but the data base is ready,this is just a short description in real time my SP will be complicated,just want to know how to get the data in model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support I have fixed it the issue was in the AllDataa class there was another class in it which is why it was not working.

```
 public class AllDataa
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

  }
```